# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility'?

Tags: asp.net, assemblies

Strange. I am trying to deploy my application, normally there is not problems but recently i played with adding LINQ2SQL to the project and adding Entity Framework.. but removed them. Now when i try to deploy to my server, running it i am getting this error.. and i can't find a way to fix it ! I never used this assembly.. but i suspect Entity Framework or LINQ2SQL to have caused this.

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Additional infos:

1. I am using a Website project and not
   a web application project.
2. I am
       using DevExpress but i added all
       their dll to the bin folder and that
       never caused any problems.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this defined anywhere in your configuration file?  Or do you know of any DLL's in your project that depend on it?

Comment: Strange. Its working now and i didn't touch anything. For like 10 minutes it wasn't working. :-/ btw.. that assembly wasn't defined in the web.config.. but also wasn't used from what i remember.. so it shouldnt do that. It never happened before. It sound like something was needed to be auto-refreshed or i don't know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this issue and solved it by removing the DevExpress.Xpf dlls from the bin folder after reading a comment on [this DevExpress thread](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q275153.aspx)

Comment: I've been trying to work out what was causing that for ages! First time into the site it failed, hit F5 and it worked. Very odd! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 6):

This DLL is part of Visual Studio. You should be able to add it through `Add Reference > Assemblies`

Hover over the name to see where the location is and pick the one corresponding to your version of Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: This always happens to me when I install a new Windows and don't have installed whatever version of the framework I had before. Updating to the latest version usually works :)